# overhead power-line safety

Tags: coaxial-cable, safety

A set of utility lines, and above them some high voltage power lines, run almost directly over the backyard fence.  Some radio antennas are situated so that they can't fall onto the utility or power lines.  However the opposite is not true.  It appears that if one or two of the power poles were to collapse slightly towards each other, some of the high power lines could potentially fall almost anywhere on the property or house.  And the house is near a major fault line.

The antenna feedline shields are grounded to a deep ground stake directly behind the house.  Are they any additional safety precautions needed on the antennas, feed-lines, or radio equipment in the house?

If I wanted to route a feedline to some very tall trees well past the power lines (by more than the height of either), are there any specific things I should do when routing under power lines for safety?

Comment: What does the electric utility recommend?

Comment: The utility has been and is being sued for destroying entire neighborhoods, some nearby.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that supports are fully anchored and supported other than that check with local codes to make sure that wires that you are putting up are away a certain amount.

If you are in a major fault line try designing a Yugi antenna that way you do not need to deal with wire antenna